# Comparing one list to see in which position it appears in another

Tags: python, list, compare

Here's my Python code which doesn't work. One list is called `sentencelist`the other is called `noduplicateslist`. For each word in `sentencelist`, I want to find that word's index in `noduplicateslist`.

For example, sentencelist may be THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT and noduplicateslist would be THE CAT SAT ON MAT. So I want it to return 1,2,3,4,1,5

I have tried:

```
for word in sentencelist:
    for x in range(len(noduplicateslist)):
            position.append[x]
            print(position)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused: what do you expect `position.append[x]` to do? I'd use `if noduplicateslist[x] == word: print x`

Comment: For example, sentencelist may be THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT and noduplicateslist would be THE CAT SAT ON MAT. So I want it to return 1,2,3,4,1,5

Comment: You should add that example to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely would benefit from reading about list.index(), as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Example usage which produces your desired output:

```
for word in sentencelist:
        print(noduplicateslist.index(word))
```